# How to traverse multiple "nested" DOM elements while also referencing a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**UPDATE:** I was able to get it to work by including a leading # into the string, like `let $cropBoxLineLeft = $('#main-image-slider .slide.active #' + $activeImageWrapper + ' .cropper-container .cropper-crop-box').find('.line-w');`

Is there any way I can condense some of that down? Just go straight from `$activeImageWrapper` to `.cropper-crop-box` then find the `.line-w`? To repeat my original post, for example, this does not work:

```
let $cropBoxLineLeft = $($activeImageWrapper).find('.cropper-container .cropper-crop-box .line-w');
```

And neither does filtering it down (though perhaps I'm misusing .filter()?)

```
let $cropBoxLineLeft = $($activeImageWrapper).filter('.cropper-crop-box').find('.line-w');
```

Do I have to run through the "full" path all the way from `#main-image-slider` down to the eventual `.line-w'`?

---

In earlier iterations I was able to find the proper element when using a "raw" string value like this:

`let $cropBoxLeftLine = $('#main-image-slider .slide.active #crop-image-wrapper .cropper-container .cropper-crop-box').find('.line-w');`

However, now I've replaced the above `#crop-image-wrapper` with something that has a unique ID associated with it, currently saved in `$activeImageWrapper`.

I've tried variations on the above selector, but I don't know how to properly "use" the jQuery object. It keeps returning "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined", so I'm obviously not selecting it properly.

For example, when i'm trying to concatenate them together, it doesn't seem to work:

`let $cropBoxLeftLine = $('#main-image-slider .slide.active ' + $activeImageWrapper + ' .cropper-container .cropper-crop-box').find('.line-w');`

Neither does trying to cut to the chase and 'find' on the object directly:

`let $cropBoxLeftLine = $($activeImageWrapper).find('.cropper-container .cropper-crop-box .line-e');`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the value of `$activeImageWrapper`? Is it a string or a jQuery object?

Comment: Where is the `nodeType` reference? Is that in your code, or is the error happening internal to jQuery?

Comment: The value for $activeImageWrapper ends up being some variation of the string "crop-image-wrapper-<id_number>", with the ending number set to match the currently slide (ie "crop-image-wrapper-1").

Comment: maybe $activeImageWrapper string needs a # at the beginning?

Comment: Thank you @Piero, I just discovered that and update my OP. Is there any way to shorten the selector? The only way I can get it to work is if I start at the initial `#main-image-slider` then work my way down to eventually arrive at the desired `.line-w`. Maybe it's no big deal and I just need to let it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$activeImageWrapper` is the ID of the element you want to select, you need to prefix it with `#` to make it the correct selector.

```
$(`#${$activeImageWrapper} .cropper-container .cropper-crop-box .line-w`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Barmar (and @Piero!)